# HTML5 video playback testing

Tags: google-chrome, testing, firefox, testcafe, drm

I am trying to use testcafe for video playback testing for html5 videos. But the browsers are invoking with disbaled drm modules. I checked for both google chrome and firefox.

For chrome I tried with option "--disable-component-update" like following but still getting drm related error("Error in retriving key message from DRM.")

```
testcafe "chrome --disable-component-update" tests/sample-fixture.js
```

How can we invoke browser without sandbox mode so we can access all browser components like drm etc.

Comment: How do you know that the browsers are invoking with disabled DRM modules - what logs are you seeing?

Comment: Because, I am getting this error from from media player(shakaplayer) "Error in retriving key message from DRM", this means the encrypted video cannot be decrypted.
This is as per this comment 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29970602/4109027

Comment: We didn't face any similar issue. Could you please share the url to your website and your test code? You can also find any similar public website that reproduces the same error. Please also specify your OS and testcafe version

Comment: Are you able to share the console logs - that does not look like a regular Shaka log? The comment post you refer to is for ChromeDriver, btw - are you using this also?

Comment: @Mick Yes the error log is our custom error. We have made our own player wrapper which contains multiple players.
Yes the comment is about chromedriver, we are not using same but I thought that testcafe also might be invoking browser in safe mode with some browser modules disabled.

Comment: As mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479888/play-drm-content-in-chrome-driver/29970602#29970602 thread, Chrome Driver launches Chrome with the `--disable-component-update` flag, which leads to problems with DRM modules.
TestCafe does not use this flag by default, and you do not need to use it. Could you clarify where you run you TestCafe tests: on CI or on the local machine? As far as I know, sometimes DRM modules are cut out on Linux CI systems.

Comment: Can you also share the underlying Shaka log - it may be that the DRM modes are there but there is some issues acquiring the license

Comment: @AlexKamaev I am testing on linux (Ubuntu) machine, so yes it could be the reason you mentioned due to whih DRM modules might be disabled.

Comment: @Mick Sure I will try to find the underlying Shakaplayer log and will share here.